# Подскажите пожалуйста как работает this в контексте данного кода JS

Tags: javascript

```js
function parallax(event) {
  console.log(this.quertySelectorAll('.layer'));
}
document.addEventListener('mousemove', parallax);
```

И если я правильно понял второй аргумент функции `addEventLisener` необходим для передачи событий в качестве аргумента event в функцию `parallax`

Comment: В вашем случае this это объект из контекста которого вызывается метод

Comment: а если такой код в тело функции parallax console.log(event.clientX); как в ивент получает данные о местоположении мыши?\

Comment: Может браузер передает:))

Comment: @Тахир event - это объект события, его создаёт браузер при каждом движении мыши по странице, и у этого объекта сразу задаётся ключ clientX и прочие. А слушатель, добавленный через addEventListener, если видит такое событие, то вызывает ваш метод parallax, помещая в него объект события в первый аргумент.

Comment: Выходит браузер регистрирует и передает значения в первый аргумент вызываемой функции?

Comment: А все уже ответили спасибо большое))

Comment: Это я и хотел узнать))

Answer (score 2):

В вашем случае это this - document. Второй параметр addEventLisener это метод который будет вызван из контекста document. Но удивительно то что если вызвать paralax из другого контекста то this будет равен ему.

Answer (score 1):

Если функция вызвана не круглыми скобками, а каким-то другим механизмом, то нужно читать документацию этого механизма, чтобы понять, что именно он делает с `this`.

В вашем случае метод `addEventListener` объекта `document` создаёт слушатель события `mousemove`. И этот слушатель при наступлении события вызывает метод `parallax`, устанавливая его this равным `document`.

Слушатель может это сделать так же, как и мы сами можем установить любой this для любой функции в момент её вызова, например методом `call`:

```
parallax.call(document.body); // тут у вашей функции this будет равен body
```

Также этот слушатель, кроме `this`, передаёт в функцию произошедшее событие как первый аргумент. Если событие называлось `mousemove`, то при его наступлении в первый аргумент функции передастся событие данного типа (объект типа [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent)).